# Adding custome emojis to an flutter project

Tags: flutter

Long story short, I have to implement an *emoji picker* in Flutter.
The requirments are :
-

- imported emojis(from PNGs or SVGs).
- posibility to use the widget across diffrent pages or attach them to
  any textfield component.
- posibility to add custom emojies created by users.

Is there any posibility to implement it?
Deep into my research I came accross pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter, but I couldn't find out a posibility to add the libraries.

Comment: You might want to use CustomIcons as your emojis are probably mostly in SVG format, you should be able to generate "custom icons" which you can use as a set of so-called icons (which will be your emojis). More info can be found here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-your-flutter-application#how-to-generate-custom-icons-in-flutter